# Angular 2 cli HTTP_PROVIDERS has no export member issue

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular 2 and not able to import HTTP_PROVIDERS from @angular/http. I have gone through many similar Questions but none of them was related to CLI.

Can anyone help me to add HTTP_PROVIDERS to Angular-cli

why are we using rxjs?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30q4Z.jpg)

Comment: HTTP_PROVIDERS is deprecated and was removed from stable version. You don't have to do anything with that. (RxJS) is a reactive streams library that allows you to work with asynchronous data streams. RxJS can be used both in the browser or in the server-side using Node.js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is no `HTTP_PROVIDERS` in angular 2.x.x it was removed. it's deprecated since Angular rc5.

if you want to use `Http` service just import `HttpModule` in your module

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to import `HTTP_PROVIDERS`, just do something like this

```
import { HttpModule, JsonpModule } from '@angular/http';
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    // other NgModule
    HttpModule,
    JsonpModule
  ],
  //...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

`why are we using rxjs?`
because rxjs is a part of Angular, the HTTP is wrap by Observable.